# How to fix "The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>" error in cucumber selenium JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, drop-down-menu, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber-jvm

I tried to use the data table and implements my function to fetch the
 values from this Cucumber data table, I used List< List< String >> but
 it doesn't work !

> public void myfunction(DataTable dt) throws Throwable {
>
> List> list = dt.asList(String.class);
>
> driver.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys(list.get(0).get(0));
>     driver.findElement(By.id("age")).sendKeys(list.get(0).get(1));
>     driver.findElement(By.id("nphone")).sendKeys(list.get(1).get(0));
>     driver.findElement(By.id("address")).sendKeys(list.get(1).get(1));
>
> }

Comment: Could you please look at the fully qualified name of `List`? I suppose it is not the `java.util.List` type, but some other `List` type.

Answer (score 2):

Using **Header** we can implement Data Table in much clean & precise way and considering Data Table looks like below one -

```
And fill up the first & last name form with the following data
    | First Name | Last Name |
    |    Tom     |    Adam   |
    |   Hyden    | Pointing  |

public void myfunction(DataTable table) throws Throwable {

List<Map<String, String>> list = table.asMaps(String.class,String.class); 

driver.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys(list.get(0).get("First Name"));
driver.findElement(By.id("age")).sendKeys(list.get(0).get("Last Name"));
driver.findElement(By.id("nphone")).sendKeys(list.get(1).get("First Name"));
driver.findElement(By.id("address")).sendKeys(list.get(1).get("Last Name"));

}
```

**Implementation Rules -** Below are 2 snippet and the most interesting snippet is the first one, the one that suggest that the argument to the method is a DataTable dataTable. The snippet suggests that you should replace the DataTable dataTable argument with any of:

```
 - List<E>
 - List<List<E>>
 - List<Map<K,V>>
 - Map<K,V>
 - Map<K, List<V>>
```

It also tells us that each type, E, K, V must be of any of these types:

- String
- Integer
- Float,
- Double
- Byte
- Short
- Long
- BigInteger
- BigDecimal

Answer (score 2):

Check your imports, please. I have downloaded java.awt.list by mistake. It worked when I imported java.util.list.

Like :

`import java.util.list;`